# Class.autoload (oversee it) and get the class manually

Tags: php, class

i'm currently creating a module in php.

Below is a function included in my main class file.

```
...
        $xmldebug = simplexml_load_file($response); 
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
            if (!$xml)
                throw new Exception(_("Registry return malformed XML"));

        $result_attributes = $xml->response->result->attributes();
        $response_code = (string)$result_attributes["code"];

            if ($response_code == RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::ERR_CMD_FAILED || 
                $response_code == RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::ERR_CMD_FAILED_END_SESSION)
                throw new Exception(_("Registry error"));


            if ($response_code == RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::ERR_CMD_FAILED_END_SESSION ||
                $response_code == RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::ERR_AUTH_END_SESSION ||
                $response_code == RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::OK_END_SESSION ||
                $response_code == RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::ERR_SESSION_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) 
                $this->IsConnected = false;

            if ($response_code == RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::ERR_OBJECT_NOT_EXISTS)
                throw new ObjectNotExistsException();
            if ($response_code == RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::ERR_OBJECT_STATUS_PROHIBITS_OP)
                throw new ProhibitedTransformException();
            if ($response_code == RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::ERR_OBJECT_EXISTS)
                throw new ObjectExistsException();
                            echo $response_code;

            $ok_codes = array(  RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::OK, 
                                RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::OK_ACK_DEQUEUE, 
                                RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::OK_END_SESSION,
                                RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::OK_NO_MESSAGES,
                                RFC3730_RESULT_CODE::OK_PENDING
                              );

            $is_success = in_array($response_code, $ok_codes);
...
```

When i was doing some tests "localy" i had the enum.RFC3730_RESULT_CODE file (which contains the RFC3730_RESULT_CODE class ) in the same directory with the other files.
Now that i tried to get this module on the platform i put the file again in the same directory as my main class but i get the below error

```
Exception: Unable to load / locate class RFC3730_RESULT_CODE IN /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/core/class.autoload.php(127)
```

class.autoload.php file is encrypted so is there any way i can oversee it and get use that RFC3730 class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manually included the file within the function that needed it. This has fixed the problem.